# How to prevent transactions from replicating in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a situation where there are plenty of `DELETE` statements in the table.

If I want to truncate the table at SLAVE, and ignore all the `DELETE` statements from one table, What might be the apt query?

Comment: If you mean the contents of the table, then you can use `DISTINCT` to get    single non replicated value. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: thank Panther.  What I mean is,    how do I make sure I catch up replication immediately which is left behind just because 99% of bin log contains DELETE from tableA ?.   Is it possible to  instruct MySQL on slave to simply ignore any DELETE statements coming for tableA ?

Comment: You can use the [`sql_slave_skip_counter`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-global-sql-slave-skip-counter.html), but you will have to check for your own which of these are the delete statements. Also you should really really check if that is what you want, because this will get your servers out of sync, which might have severe consequences later, because any statement that involves this table might produce different results on the master and the slave. Maybe you should just reset your replication (and load all data fresh from your master).

Comment: thanks Solarflare,  how about  these two options (1) truncate table at slave so that DELETE statements will *just not do anything* or will it fail ? (2) is there any way too tell MySQL at SLAVE side to simply ignore all the transactions for a particular table  ?

Comment: Yes, you can do both; for (1), the delete will just not do anything if the table is empty, but will still execute (so it still might take (a little) time). Songlei gave you the link to option (2) in a comment to his answer; it will ignore everything, not just deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just ignore some tables instead of statement.
If you make sure all the delete statements are one table of operations.You can ignore this table during the replication, then operate this table yourself.

Comment: thanks wang but how to tell MySQL to ignore tables to be replicated at Slave, what is the command ?

Comment: use  --replicate-ignore-table or --replicate-wild-ignore-table options before starting replication. you can view the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-rules-table-options.html

Comment: thanks wang, I looked at that options, looks like that might do the trick, however I am not sure if this option will take effect for transactions which are coming in to primary after this option is set OR this option will start ignoring DELETE statements for a table which are already logged into binary log and yet to be replicated ?

Comment: It just restricts the relay log which will be executed by SQL thread. The master's binary log and the slave's relay log which is logged by IO thread will not be affected

Comment: thanks a ton want , you saved my day :-),   after I ignored replication for this table, my replication is back to normal now